# right align ion-select within ion-navbar

Tags: css, ionic-framework

In the existing code the ion-select is seen just near the end of

I want to place the  ion-select at the right most position of the ion-navbar.

**home.html**

```
<ion-header  >
<ion-navbar  align-title="left" >
  <button  ion-button menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>

 <ion-row>
    <div>
      <p style="color:white;">CoolManz!!</p>
    </div>
      <div >
          <ion-item >
                    <ion-label>Gender</ion-label>
                    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender">
                      <ion-option value="f">Female</ion-option>
                      <ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
                    </ion-select>
            </ion-item>
        </div>
  </ion-row>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

[image: Current ion-select]

Comment: you seem to have a minor typo with `ion-option` in your code..

Comment: also is this ionic v2+?

Comment: @SurajRao yes,Version:3.12.0

Answer (score 4):

This works for me in Ionic 3+

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
  <button ion-button menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>

 <ion-row>
    <ion-title>Jobs</ion-title>
     <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender">
          <ion-option value="f">Female</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
  </ion-row>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

[image]